# Asymptotic property of estimators

Tags: econometrics, estimators, asymptotics

I'm studying the asymptotic properties of estimators.

Let $\{ \hat{\theta}_T : T=1,2,3... \}$ be a sequence of estimators of the $p \times1$ vector $\theta \in \Theta $, and $T$ is the sample size. Then, by assuming that my consistent estimator has the following asymptotic distribution:

$\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta}_T-\theta) \sim N(0,V)$

where $V$ is a $p \times p $ positive semidefinite matrix.

Then, we can assume $\hat{\theta}_T \sim N(\theta,V/T)$

I understand we have the factor $\sqrt{T}$ in the asymptotic distribution of the consistent estimator $\hat{\theta}$ because $(\hat{\theta}_T-\theta)$ has a degenerate distribution.
Can you show me why $(\hat{\theta}_T-\theta)$ has a degenerate distribution? That's what Marno Verbeek is saying

[image]

Comment: You seem sometimes to treat "$N$" as an integer and at other times to treat it as implying some kind of limiting operation has been performed.  You seem to mean "$\sim$" in the sense of "is approximately distributed as," whereas it usually means "is *exactly* distributed as."  This makes it difficult to understand what you're trying to ask.  The reason for the factor $1/\sqrt N$ has nothing to do with degeneracy and everything to do with standardizing this sequence so that it has some useful, analyzable limit.

Comment: Question restated by adding references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, instead of stating "$\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta}_T - \theta) \color{red}{\sim} N(0, V)$" for asymptotic normality of the estimator sequence $\{\hat{\theta}_T\}$, the correct notation should be $\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta}_T - \theta) \color{red}{\to_d} N(0, V)$. In words, this means *$\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta}_T - \theta)$ converges to $N(0, V)$ in distribution (or in law/weakly)*. The "$\sim$" notation stands for the distributional form following it is **exact**, but not asymptotically.  By the same token, you should not say "$\hat{\theta}_T - \theta$" **has** a degenerate distribution" (I see your reference, which is not that accurate either and probably misled you), a more precise statement would be "$\hat{\theta}_T - \theta$ **converges in distribution to a degenerate distribution as $T \to \infty$**".

That said, what you are interested is an immediate consequence of the [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).  Write
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}_T - \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{T}} \times \sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta}_T - \theta),
\end{align}
$1/\sqrt{T} \to 0$ and $\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta}_T - \theta) \to_d N(0, V)$ together imply that their product converges in distribution to the product of $0$ and $N(0, V)$, which is $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I was clear that I was referring to the asymptotic distribution for the random variable $\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta_T} - \theta$). Btw, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JohnM. I understand what you meant.  However, using that "$\sim$" notation actually couldn't convey this meaning well.  That is why we suggested you changing a more accurate notation for it.  FYI, some authors used the notation "$\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta}_T - \theta) \text{ is } AN(0, V)$", which is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: You are right, thanks again